# Does the Cloud9 has the Syntax automatically?

Tags: cloud9-ide, developer-tools

I want make my code more regular,does the cloud9 has this function?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can format your code with the shortcut `ctrl/cmd + shift + b`. You can also find this functionality under Edit -> Code Formatting in the Cloud9 menu.